# $ \nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \Delta \rho=\operatorname{div}\left(\nabla^{2} \rho \nabla \rho\right)-\left|\nabla^{2} \rho\right|^{2} $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

In the book *[Entropy Methods for Diffusive Partial Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-34219-1)*,  §2.1, p. 21 it says:
$$
\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla \Delta \rho=\operatorname{div}\left(\nabla^{2} \rho \nabla \rho\right)-\left|\nabla^{2} \rho\right|^{2}
$$

Can somebody explain where this comes from?

Comment: Rearranged, this is product rule, albeit its a little weird they decided to mix and match notations instead of leaning into $\nabla^3\rho$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Define $\nabla^3$.  Is it $\nabla \nabla\cdot \nabla$?  Or is it a tensor $\nabla \nabla \nabla $?  Or is is another operator?

Comment: It could be the first option, or it could be a third option $(\nabla\cdot nabla) \nabla$! It's nice that they commute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the product rule $\nabla \cdot (\phi \vec A)=\nabla \phi\cdot \vec A+\phi \nabla \cdot \vec A$, with $\phi =\nabla^2 \rho$ and $\vec A=\nabla \rho, $we have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \rho \cdot \nabla^2 \nabla \rho& =\underbrace{\nabla \rho}_{\vec A} \cdot  \nabla(\underbrace{\nabla^2 \rho}_{=\phi})\\\\
&=\nabla \cdot \left( \underbrace{\nabla \rho}_{\vec A} \,\underbrace{\nabla^2 \rho}_{\phi}\right)-\underbrace{\nabla^2\rho}_{\phi} \,\underbrace{ \nabla^2 \rho}_{\nabla \cdot \vec A}\\\\
&=\nabla \cdot \left(  \nabla^2 \rho \nabla \rho\right)-\left|\nabla^2\rho \right|^2
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!